# PointCloud from array of disparity map

Tags: python, opencv, 3d-reconstruction

I have to reconstruction a 3d object from a set of image. Suppose i have already done the camera calibration for all the images (form example 10 images, all of them display the subject in different angles). I create an array of disparity map (for example the first one with image 1 and 2 the second one with image 2 and 3 and so on), after that i have to create a point cloud of all disparities map how can i do that? below is show the code i use to process only 2 image.

```
stereo = cv2.StereoSGBM_create(minDisparity= min_disp,
    numDisparities = num_disp,
    blockSize = 5,
    uniquenessRatio = 5,
    speckleWindowSize = 5,
    speckleRange = 5,
    disp12MaxDiff = 1,
    P1 = 8*3*win_size**2,#8*3*win_size**2,
    P2 =32*3*win_size**2) #32*3*win_size**2)
#Compute disparity map
print ("\nComputing the disparity  map...")
disparity_map = stereo.compute(img_1_downsampled, img_2_downsampled)

Q = np.float32([[1,0,0,-w/2.0],
                [0,-1,0,h/2.0],
                [0,0,0,-focal_length],
                [0,0,1,0]])

points_3D = cv2.reprojectImageTo3D(disparity_map, Q)
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this? I extracted a disparity map from a TrueDepth photo and I would like to import it to Blender as a point cloud.